# How to show grouped by in Chart using Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have table

```
Transactions {
TransactionId
TransactionDate
TotalIncome
}
```

And I want to show `totalIncome` of years of `TransactionDate`
Lets say I have following data in my database

```
 TransactionId  TransactionDate TotalIncome
 1              2017-10-12       230
 2              2017-11-10       400
 3              2018-01-03       300
 4              2018-10-05       500    
 5              2019-01-06       600
 6              2019-02-10       200
```

So I want to see in chart with `charttype` Spline like for `2017` show `630` because `230+400 = 630`  for `2018` show `800` and so on.
So I want to see in Chart Years as `x-axis` and total income in `y-axis`

What's wrong I am doing when I write like this?

```
 public DisplayForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        var series = chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
        series.XValueMember = "Year";
        series.YValueMembers = "TotalIncome";
        ShowSoldProduct(); 
    }

  private void ShowSoldProduct()
    {
        using (HotelEntities db = new HotelEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var result = (from pr in db.Transactions
                              select pr).ToArray();

                chart1.DataSource = result
                    .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.Year)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Year = g.Key,

                        TotalIncome = g.Sum(y => y.TotalPrice)
                    })
                    .ToArray();

                chart1.DataSource = result;
                chart1.DataBind();
                chart1.Show();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: You have prepared the data members of your series but you are binding the chart instead of the series.Points. - You should also describe what happens!

Comment: And, of course, as mm8 shows, if you want to group by year you ought to do that..

Comment: @TaW thank you as allways for responding. When I did as mm8 it givs me error at chart1.DataBind() , the error says " "Series data points do not support values of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Transactions.......TypeDescriptor only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by `TransactionDate.Year`. I am not sure if Entity Framework (or whatever ORM you are using) supports this but you might as well group the in-memory results. Something like this:

```
var result = (from pr in db.Transactions
              select pr).ToArray();

chart1.DataSource = result
    .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Year)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Year = g.Key
        TotalIncome = g.Sum(y => y.TotalIncome)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This givs me error at Chart1.DataBind() The error says "Series data points do not support values of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Transactions.......TypeDescriptor only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort."

Comment: My sample code sets the `DataSource` to an array of anonymous types...debug your code to find out what you are setting the property to.

Comment: Thank you for response, I don not know what I will debug but I have edited my code as your code  and it's exactly what it looks like in my projeckt. Can you please check my edited code and see wha tI'am doing wrong?

Comment: You set `chart1.DataSource` twice. Remove `chart1.DataSource = result;`.

Comment: O.M.G it's true,  .. It's working now ...;) Thank you very much!

Comment: If I want to show two more table togateher with Transacstion table how would be then looks like the code? I have two more tables one called expenditureTable and InvestmentTable. Both have dates and value looks like alomost like Transaction table. If I want to show all three table in the same Chart How should your code look like then? I know I have to add more series like .. var series2 = chart1.Series.Add("expenditure");  series3 = chart1.Series.Add("Investment");.. But how will I reforme chart1.DataSource = result ....? Thank you again.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: Thank you, I have now another issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670007/c-sharp-chart-from-multiple-tables-windows-form

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication100
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("TransactionId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TransactionDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalIncome", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DateTime.Parse("2017-10-12"), 230 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DateTime.Parse("2017-11-10"), 400 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-03"), 300 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, DateTime.Parse("2018-10-05"), 500 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, DateTime.Parse("2019-01-06"), 600 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, DateTime.Parse("2019-02-10"), 200 });

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("TransactionDate").Year)
                .Select(x => new { year = x.Key, total = x.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("TotalIncome")) })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```