# Chart from multiple tables

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

[image]
I have three tables named Deposit, Debit and Transfer,
like

```
Deposit  { DepositID, DepostDate, Amount}
Debit    { DebitID, DebitDate, Amount}
Transfer { TransferID, TransferDate, Amount}
```

How can I show all three tables in one chart? I am even wondering if it is better to put those three tables into one table instead, like

```
Transaction {TransactionId, TransactionTypeId, TransactionDate, Amount}
```

where TransactiontypeId could be 1 = for Deposit, 2 for Debit and 3 for Transfer and bind this transaction table to the chart. 
Let's say I have all those in one table instead and with table name Transactions then @mm8 helped me figure this out:

```
 var result = (from pr in db.Transactions 
                  join tr in db.TransactionType on pr.TrTypeId equals tr.TransactionTypeId
                  select new
                  {
                      TransactionDate = pr.TransactionDate,
                      TransactionType = tr.TrType,
                      Amount = pr.Amount

                  }).ToList();

chart1.DataSource = result
 .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.Year)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Year = g.Key,
        TransactionType = g. //////
        Amount = g.Sum(y => y.Amount)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Is is better to have a chart from one table or from multiple tables and how to do multiple.

I am aware that I have to create different series for every table like this:

```
var Depseries = chart1.Series.Add("Deposit");
Depseries.XValueMember = "Year";
Depseries.YValueMembers = "DepositAmount";
Depseries.Name = "Deposit";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series["Deposit"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Depseries.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";

// Debit

var Debseries = chart1.Series.Add("Debit");
Debseries.XValueMember = "Year";
Debseries.YValueMembers = "DebitAmount";
Debseries.Name = "Debit";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series["Debit"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Debseries.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";

// Transfer
var FDseries = chart1.Series.Add("Transfer");
FDseries.XValueMember = "Year";
FDseries.YValueMembers = "TransferAmount";
FDseries.Name = "Transfer";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series["Transfer"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
FDseries.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";
```

Comment: Download the msdn samples.  Lot of very good examples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Forms-Samples-26bf2a53

Comment: As it stands the question is both unclear and opinion-based.

Comment: @TaW thank you Taw and I understand you.Even for me it was diffcult to formulate my question ;)  Let say I have 3 tables as I wrote in the begining Deposit table, Debit table and Transfer table each of one have Date and amount. How can I show them in the same chart?

Comment: You have started out quite ok, imo. What is key is to know just what the result should look like. Do they have a common x-axis? The Year maybe? Then you can do just what you wrote: bind each resultset to a different Series..

Comment: @TaW yes Year is common x-axis. May I aske you .. Please write your code I'am so new to this staffs and confused.  I tried by different methods but I do not see the result.  I realy appricate your help.

Comment: You ought to bind each Series.Points not the whole chart. So replace `chart1.DataSource` by `chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(result1, "yourXmemberName", result1, "yourYmemberName")` etc for the other series and result sets..!

Comment: @TaW , Thank you Taw, But Can you Please check my code Inside GroupBy .... it's even there I do not know how to do.

Comment: @TaW I think we have missunderstanding with each other. Can you please rewrite my hole code so I understand what you mean?

Comment: The rule about a GROUPBY select is: Select only the group field and also functions to pick some value from the group. SUM does just that. TransactionType is unclear. If it varies in the group, what would be a useful function??? If it doesn't a FIRST or a MAX could do..

Comment: @JonasWillander: So you have three tables with a date and an amount in each one. What exactly do you want to do with these?

Comment: @mm8 Yes as you said I want to show together in one chart  year as x -axis and Y as Amount. I mean three amounts in each year ... almost as you see in pictutre (attached image), It's almost like you helped me before from one table, but now from three tables instead. Is this posible?  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just select the data from each of the tables and then use the `DataBind` method to populate the series with data, e.g.:

```
var deposits = (from x in db.Deposits select new { x.DepositDate, x.Amount })
    .ToArray()
    .GroupBy(x => x.DepositDate.Year)
    .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(y => y.Amount) })
    .ToArray();
var Depseries = chart1.Series.Add("Deposit");
Depseries.XValueMember = "Year";
Depseries.YValueMembers = "DepositAmount";
Depseries.Name = "Deposit";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series["Deposit"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Depseries.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";
chart1.Series["Deposit"].Points.DataBind(deposits, "Year", "Amount", null);

var debits = (from x in db.Debits select new { x.DebitDate, x.Amount })
    .ToArray()
    .GroupBy(x => x.DebitDate.Year)
    .Select(g => new { Year = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(y => y.Amount) })
    .ToArray();
var Debseries = chart1.Series.Add("Debit");
Debseries.XValueMember = "Year";
Debseries.YValueMembers = "DebitAmount";
Debseries.Name = "Debit";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chart1.Series["Debit"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Debseries.CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";
chart1.Series["Debit"].Points.DataBind(debits, "Year", "Amount", null);

...
```

Comment: Wonderful! It's working. I hade no Idea about Points.DataBind. Waw ... Thank you so much!

Comment: I thought I did, but which one did I forgot to do?

Comment: I see .. you know I'am amateur ;)